# How to populate a DropDownList based on the selection from another DropDownList?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two DropDownLists in my windows form say `combobox1` and `combobox2`. I am getting the data into `combobox1` from database table using MySQL. I am storing all the departments names of an organization as the values into the `combobox1`. So when I select an item in `combobox1` all the employees related to that department should be displayed into `combobox2`.

e.g. if I select "management", all the employees in the "management" department should be displayed in `combobox2`

The problem here is that whatever I select, every time the values in the `combobox2` are displaying all the employees of the entire organization and not the employees related to the selected department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your department into your SQL:

```
select * from employees where department = &selectedDepartment
```

Or if you are using LINQ:

```
var employees = dc.Employees.Where(e => e.Department == selectedDepartment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are doing but it sounds like you are repopulating combo box 2 with all values.

Can you listen for the selection changed event on combo box 1 and then populate combo box 2 dynamically when the selection for combo box 1 changes.